# How to query datastore entities with GeoPtProperty?

Tags: mongodb, google-app-engine, nosql, app-engine-ndb, datastore

My app is deployed by Google App Engine, this app can upload a lot of stores with their coordinates saved as GeoPt(lat, long) to the datastore.

But after the store is uploaded, I want to query these stores by the user's coordinates in certain range. For example, if there are 4 stores located at (10,11), (11,10), (10, 9), (9, 10) and the user is located at (10, 10). What I want to do is if I query the distance in 100 miles, these stores will be queried.

I hope the query could be something like this:

```
stores = Store.query(( Store.coordinates - user.coordinates < 100 )).fetch()
```

But I didn't find any function related to datastore.
Anyone suggestion please?

Comment: How exactly are you using mongodb in your app?

Comment: @VictorHerasmePerez I don't know what is your 'exactly' meaning. If you mean what's the relation between this question and mongodb. In GCP, the datastore has the almost same functionality with mongodb.
If you mean what I really want to do with datastore, I want to query all the store with certain range with GeoPtProperty.

Comment: There might be a solution but it involves the Search API rather than Datastore. Read this https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/search/query_strings#Python_Queries_on_geopoint_fields

Comment: @VictorHerasmePerez Ya, I have looked it up before, but it's kind of complicated for me. I mean, this isn't directly use the datastore query to solve the problem, so I didn't read it deep. Anyway, this might be the solution if I reach the end of the rope.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Weird query comparison of GeoPt in google ndb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49253141/weird-query-comparison-of-geopt-in-google-ndb)